# Traverse through object and insert elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Let's say I have this:

```js
const data = [
  {
    table: [
      [{
        textValue: 'One'
      },
      {
        textValue: 'Two',
        rows: 3
      },
      {
        textValue: 'Three',
        rows: 3
      },
      {
        textValue: 'Four'
      }],
      [{
        textValue: 'RED',
        rows: 2
      },
      {
        textValue: 'GREEN'
      },
      {
        textValue: 'BLUE',
        rows: 1
      }]
    ]
  }
];
```

What I am going after is where it traverses through the object (`Object.entries()` would work?) and see that `rows` exists and inserts `X` number of empty `''` strings, so you'd have something like:

```
const data = [
  {
    table: [
      [{
        textValue: 'One'
      },
      {
        textValue: 'Two',
        rows: 3
      },
        '',
        '',
        '',
      {
        textValue: 'Three',
        rows: 3
      },
        '',
        '',
        '',
      {
        textValue: 'Four'
      }],
      [{
        textValue: 'RED',
        rows: 2
      },
        '',
        '',
      {
        textValue: 'GREEN'
      },
      {
        textValue: 'BLUE',
        rows: 1
      },
      ''
      ]
    ]
  }
];
```

I thought about using a `for in` but then I won't know the parent object to edit it when it comes time to push the element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) which will return an array of your inserted string characters based on the number of `rows` for the given object, that will be flattened into the resulting array:

```js
const data = [{ table: [ [{ textValue: 'One' }, { textValue: 'Two', rows: 3 }, { textValue: 'Three', rows: 3 }, { textValue: 'Four' } ], [{ textValue: 'RED', rows: 2 }, { textValue: 'GREEN' }, { textValue: 'BLUE', rows: 1 } ] ] }];

const result = data.map(obj => ({
  ...obj,
  table: obj.table.map(arr =>
    arr.flatMap((iobj) => [iobj, ...Array(iobj.rows || 0).fill('')])
  )
}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important;} /* ignore */
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of extending data object I would copy its content to a new table with proper reducer method to ease the process, shall be easy as:

```
const transformedTable = data[0].table.map(e => e.reduce((acc, val) => ([...acc, val, ...(new Array(val.rows || 0)).fill('')]), []));
```

```js
const data = [
      {
        table: [
          [{
            textValue: 'One'
          },
          {
            textValue: 'Two',
            rows: 3
          },
          {
            textValue: 'Three',
            rows: 3
          },
          {
            textValue: 'Four'
          }],
          [{
            textValue: 'RED',
            rows: 2
          },
          {
            textValue: 'GREEN'
          },
          {
            textValue: 'BLUE',
            rows: 1
          }]
        ]
      }
    ];

const transformedTable = data[0].table.map(e => e.reduce((acc, val) => ([...acc, val, ...(new Array(val.rows || 0)).fill('')]), []));

document.querySelector('#result').innerText = JSON.stringify(transformedTable);
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan) and is a bit more flexible. Using vanilla javascript might be the better choice, but that depends on your requirements

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const data = [{ table: [[ { textValue: 'One' }, { textValue: 'Two', rows: 3 }, { textValue: 'Three', rows: 3 }, { textValue: 'Four' } ], [ { textValue: 'RED', rows: 2 }, { textValue: 'GREEN' }, { textValue: 'BLUE', rows: 1 } ]] }];

const modify = (obj) => objectScan(['[*].table[*][*].rows'], {
  rtn: 'count',
  filterFn: ({ gparent, gproperty, value }) => {
    gparent.splice(gproperty + 1, 0, ...Array(value).fill(''));
  }
})(obj);

console.log(modify(data)); // returns number of modifications
// => 4

console.log(data);
// => [ { table: [ [ { textValue: 'One' }, { textValue: 'Two', rows: 3 }, '', '', '', { textValue: 'Three', rows: 3 }, '', '', '', { textValue: 'Four' } ], [ { textValue: 'RED', rows: 2 }, '', '', { textValue: 'GREEN' }, { textValue: 'BLUE', rows: 1 }, '' ] ] } ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@15.0.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)